# GL Errors on BakedOpRenderer

Tags: android

I have weird errors on an android emulator MacOsX. This android app is running well on a real device. I've been googling it a lot, but there are few thread discussions about it. I just developed fragment using a basic relative layout. When I run it, I get these errors

> 08-09 10:07:00.973 4271-4466/com.xxx.xxx E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error: 0x506
>
> 08-09 10:07:00.973 4271-4466/com.xxx.xxx A/OpenGLRenderer: GL errors! frameworks/base/libs/hwui/BakedOpRenderer.cpp:98
>
> 08-09 10:07:00.973 4271-4466/com.xxx.xxx A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 4466 (RenderThread)
>
> [ 08-09 10:07:00.974  1261: 1261 W/]
>                                           debuggerd: handling request: pid=4271 uid=10085 gid=10085 tid=4466

Is there anyway to debug it to show more error details or fix this error? This error causes the app to crash.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't quite an answer (yet), but I'm posting in the hope that it'll help get to one.

So, I just hit this on my Pixel XL in chrome, and looking into the source, we're hitting an "assert" in [BakedOpRenderer.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/libs/hwui/BakedOpRenderer.cpp):

```
void BakedOpRenderer::endLayer() {
    if (mRenderTarget.stencil) {
        // if stencil was used for clipping, detach it and return it to pool
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
        GL_CHECKPOINT(MODERATE);
        mCaches.renderBufferCache.put(mRenderTarget.stencil);
        mRenderTarget.stencil = nullptr;
    }
    mRenderTarget.lastStencilClip = nullptr;
    mRenderTarget.offscreenBuffer->updateMeshFromRegion();
    mRenderTarget.offscreenBuffer = nullptr; // It's in drawLayerOp's hands now.
    // Detach the texture from the FBO
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0);
    GL_CHECKPOINT(LOW);
    mRenderState.deleteFramebuffer(mRenderTarget.frameBufferId);
    mRenderTarget.frameBufferId = 0;
```

}

Where we're hitting the `GL_CHECKPOINT(LOW)` block.

The macro is [defined in GLUtils.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/libs/hwui/utils/GLUtils.h) as:

```
#if DEBUG_OPENGL
#define GL_CHECKPOINT(LEVEL) \
    do { if (DEBUG_OPENGL >= DEBUG_LEVEL_##LEVEL) {\
    LOG_ALWAYS_FATAL_IF(android::uirenderer::GLUtils::dumpGLErrors(),\
        "GL errors! %s:%d", __FILE__, __LINE__);\
} } while (0)
#else
#define GL_CHECKPOINT(LEVEL)
#endif
```

(`DEBUG_OPENGL` seems to default to `DEBUG_LEVEL_LOW`)

The function that actually does the work, dumpGLErrors, is [defined in GLUtils.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/libs/hwui/utils/GLUtils.cpp), as:

```
bool GLUtils::dumpGLErrors() {
#if DEBUG_OPENGL >= DEBUG_LEVEL_HIGH
    // If DEBUG_LEVEL_HIGH is set then every GLES call is already wrapped
    // and asserts that there was no error. So this can just return success.
    return false;
#else
    bool errorObserved = false;
    GLenum status = GL_NO_ERROR;
    while ((status = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        errorObserved = true;
        switch (status) {
        case GL_INVALID_ENUM:
            ALOGE("GL error:  GL_INVALID_ENUM");
            break;
        case GL_INVALID_VALUE:
            ALOGE("GL error:  GL_INVALID_VALUE");
            break;
        case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:
            ALOGE("GL error:  GL_INVALID_OPERATION");
            break;
        case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
            ALOGE("GL error:  Out of memory!");
            break;
        default:
            ALOGE("GL error: 0x%x", status);
        }
    }
    return errorObserved;
#endif
}
```

Here, my problem gets weird. You have the `GL error: 0x506` line in your log, but I don't.

Your error is [an `GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error#Meaning_of_errors) error, and it looks like [you need to look into that](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Framebuffer_Completeness).

However, if you wanted to get more info, you'd need to recompile the Android hwui lib with something like `DEBUG_LEVEL_HIGH`, and maybe a [other options](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-release/libs/hwui/Debug.h).

On my side, I have no clue, since the crash in chrome didn't leave the "GL error" in `logcat`. Grr.